# Copy Table with dependencies and rename it in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dependencies

I have a table with a bunch of dependencies. I need to add a column in the middle. To solve this, I created a new table with the additional column in the middle.

Now I need to transfer all the dependencies and then I am planning to rename the table, so the new table with the new column will satisfy it's dependencies.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with using alter table on the original table?

Comment: SQL has no concept of anything "in the middle". Just `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` and organize your columns in any order you like *at the presentation layer* (i.e. your `SELECT` statement or whatever UI you are using).